# Vectorizing this for-loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I was wondering how I would vectorize this for loop. Given a `2x2x2` array `x` and an array where each element is the `ith, jth, and kth` element of the array I want to get `x[i,j,k]`

Given an arrays `x` and `y`

```
x = np.arange(8).reshape((2, 2, 2))
y = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
```

I want to get:

`x[0, 1, 1] = 3` and `x[1, 1, 0] = 6`

I tried:

```
print(x[y])
```

But it prints:

```
array([[2, 3],
       [6, 7],
       [4, 5]])
```

So I ended up doing:

```
for y_ in y:
    print(x[y_[0], y_[1], y_[2]])
```

Which works, but I can't help but think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transposed `y` i.e `zip(*y)` as the index; You need to have the indices for each dimension as an element for [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to work:

```
x[tuple(zip(*y))]
# array([3, 6])
```